# Can't get selected place information using Place Picker

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) tutorial to use place picker. Here It is not mentioned that where should be the `onActivityResult()` method placed. So I've tried following code to get details of selected place. But can't get any responses.

My main activity named `MapActivity`:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */

int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));



    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

I also don't know where `PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();` should be placed.

I've tried many time to search for this, but I can't get perfect solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call this code `startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);` in a Map activity, it should be called from a non-map activity, probably after a button click (it's up to you).

Example with some pseudocode:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mButton;

  @Override
  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  mButton.setOnCLickListener(...);
}

private void onButtonClicked() {
// this opens a new activity with a place picker
   PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
   startActivityForResult(builder.build(this),PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // when you click back from place picker, it is handled in this method
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```